# Public Background worker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, public

So using this solution for background worker implementation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx), how can I realize public version of that? I don't want to multiply this piece of code across all my forms (I have about 4 forms and I want use background worker in all of them). Basically, I want to create 1 class and use this class as "master" (just pass control of start/cancel button, progress bar and sub which should work under "Do work").

Could you please show me a way how can I do it? I tried a lot of staff but I am not sure in the correctness. For example, should I use Public event and delegate for this purpose?

Thank you in advance

//My suggestion for "master" backgroundworker". Sorry this is untested code, I just put draft.

```
Public class BgW 
    'Event for start/cancel button. On each form there is button which raise 
    'this event and then this event raise procedure to
    'start/cancel process (event passes arguments like 
    'sender of the button to distinguish start or cancel 'button)
    Public btnclick Event (sender,e)

    Dim WithEvents as Bgw

    Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    '??? - will trigered to implement below procedure
    AddHandler ??????, AddressOf bw_DoWork
    AddHandler ?????, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
    AddHandler ??????, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted

End Sub


   Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BgW.btnclick 'this is a triger to run this procedure
    'Depends on sender I will do next controls
    sender(start).Enabled = False
    sender(cancel).Enabled = True

    TestWorker = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
    TestWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    TestWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    TestWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BgW.btnclick 'this triger to stop worker
    TestWorker.CancelAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub TestWorker_DoWork(SomeSub As Sub, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles TestWorker.DoWork
        If TestWorker.CancellationPending Then
            Exit For
        Else
           'implement procedure. I will pass some sub to implement it here.
            SomeSub()
        End If

End Sub
end class
```

I understood that I have very poor understanding of background worker, but it's my vision. Please help me how can I manage this problem.

Comment: Well, then show us what you've tried. That makes it easier for us.

Comment: Sorry, I just finished edition. My idea is to use below procedure all around my application. Passing sender of the button and using public events, but it didn't work. I spent a lot of time on that, finally just remove everything and put here how I want to make it work. This is not right code, I am just put it to catch my idea. Does anyone has preliminary solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you know this site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

The very first time, I dealed with a backgroundworker, I had the same problems as you. Here is the code of your questionmarks:

```
AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted
```

Remember to read the link above, because this howto from microsoft has a good example how to run a backgroundworker.

There is no problem, if you wish to have it in one class and make an instance of the class to run the BGW. If this, you should code a Public Sub, which starts the Private BGW.